# Deploying a forked repro of an azure quick start template

Tags: azure, github

newbie at Github.

I have forked the repro of Azure Quickstart Templates and changed the "install_lamp_moodle.sh" for the "moodle-singlevm-ubuntu" to fit my needs but I cant seem to be able to test this as every-time the newuserscript part of the azuredeploy.json template (which I have locally stored), fails

I have changed the path to the installscript URI from:

```
"installScriptUri": "[concat('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/moodle-singlevm-ubuntu/', variables('installScriptName'))]",`
```

to

```
"installScriptUri": "[concat('https://github.com/albertramsbottom/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/moodle-singlevm-ubuntu/', variables('installScriptName'))]",
```

And I am using Azure power-shell to create the resource Group and run the template

fails every time on a 404 error for the newuserscript

Obviously doing something very silly here. As I do not know Github I dont want to make changes to anything and thought that by forking the repro I could attempt this. And I have no idea where is newuserscript lives, I assume its an extension for Linux.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 08:56:02 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions
'myVM/newuserscript' failed with message 'The resource operation completed with terminal
provisioning state 'Failed'.'At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName mygroup -TemplateFile C:\T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 08:56:02 - VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'newuserscript'.
Error message: "Script returned an error.
---stdout---
---errout---
install_lamp_moodle.sh: 6: install_lamp_moodle.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
".At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName mygroup -TemplateFile C:\T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand
```

I know this sounds like an Azure quickstart issue but I think it is really a lack of understanding of GitHub and how to use a forked repro

And I aslo assume this has noting to do with the moodle-singlevm-ubuntu template and has more to do with my idiocy :)

Sorry #

Answer (score 0):

You want to link to the "raw" file URI like in the original template.  So something like:

```
"installScriptUri": "[concat('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/albertramsbottom/azure-quickstart-templates/master/moodle-singlevm-ubuntu/', variables('installScriptName'))]"
```

Note that that location has to be publicly accessible.  For a model on how to stage artifacts in a private location you can take a look at this repo:

https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples

Comment: Yes I think I need to use these files locally because I also have a deployment-azureresourceGroup.ps1 script that has been given to me but do not have currently Visual Studio

Comment: The Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 from VS doesn't have any dependencies on VS, you can run it from standalone PowerShell.  It's more or less identical to the version in the repo above.